# Use Service Worker to intercept requests on the first load of my site?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

TL;DR - I want my service worker to activate immediately after the first visit to my site, instead of after the first refresh.

Details:

I have built a progressive web app using service worker, but have noticed that on the first load (when the SW is installed) it will not intercept any network requests until the user refreshes the page.

Is there anything I can do to have the service worker start immediately intercepting requests after it is installed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can indeed, by using a combination of [`skipWaiting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting) and [`clients.claim`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#clients-claim-method) as seen below.

This will cause the service worker to immediately take control of network requests from the page.

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  // Bypass the waiting lifecycle stage,
  // just in case there's an older version of this SW registration.
  event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  // Take control of all pages under this SW's scope immediately,
  // instead of waiting for reload/navigation.
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```

Comment: Are there any disadvantages/drawbacks to doing this? (Why is this behavior not the default?)

Comment: AFAICT this does not work. See https://github.com/gaye/bug-1206947 which does this but doesn't see requests in sw on first page load.

Comment: I think the behavior I'm seeing might be the result of using hard refresh. It doesn't seem possible to use a service worker on a hard refresh (even with `self.skipWaiting()` and `self.clients.claim()` as shown above.

Comment: It's unnecessary to pass `skipWaiting()` to `event.waitUntil()`: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/commit/dbca5f70c8beec398b7bde257983ede212c4b25d#commitcomment-18602562